Creating box plot with starting and ending values for each category
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = [['Math', 3, 5, 15],
        ['English', 3, 10, 20],
        ['Computers', 5, 12, 30],
        ['Science', 8, 15, 32],
        ['Art', 17, 25, 48],
        ['Sports', 22, 45, 60]]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Class', 'First Rank','Second Rank', 'Third Rank'])

I am attempting to create a bar plot for each category. The dataframe has three columns. First Rank should be where the box starts, Second Rank should be a line in the box, and Third Rank should be where the box ends.
df2 = pd.melt(df, ['Class'])
g = sns.catplot(x="value", y='Class', hue='Class', data=df2, errorbar=None, native_scale=True, kind="box", orient="h", height=5, aspect=2)
g.set(xticks=(range(0, 80, 5)))

This code produces this plot:

This graph is wrong because I don't want to show confidence intervals. I want the box to start and end where the intervals start and end. The line in the box is correct.
I want the graph to look like this:
Numbers not needed to be on the graph. I put them there for clarity.


You could use matplotlib's bxp to plot the boxes from the aggregated value. This way you can decide exactly what is used for each parameter of the boxes. The required parameters are whislow/q1/med/q3/whishi (they can be nan):
      whislow    q1    med    q3    whishi
                  |-----:-----|
  o      |--------|     :     |--------|    o  o
                  |-----:-----|
flier                                      fliers

In your case:
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

required = ['q1', 'med', 'q3', 'whislo', 'whishi']

# compute the statistics
d = (df
   .set_index('Class')
   .agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1)
   .rename(columns={'min': 'q1', 'median': 'med', 'max': 'q3'})
   .reindex(columns=required)
   .to_dict('index')
)

# create graph
ax = plt.subplot()

x = ax.bxp(d.values(), vert=False, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(list(d))
ax.invert_yaxis()

# add custom colors
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('tab10')
for b, m, c in zip(x['boxes'], x['medians'], cmap.colors):
    b.set_facecolor(c)
    m.set_color('k')

Output:

Intermediate d:
{'Math': {'q1': 3.0, 'med': 5.0, 'q3': 15.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan},
 'English': {'q1': 3.0, 'med': 10.0, 'q3': 20.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan},
 'Computers': {'q1': 5.0, 'med': 12.0, 'q3': 30.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan},
 'Science': {'q1': 8.0, 'med': 15.0, 'q3': 32.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan},
 'Art': {'q1': 17.0, 'med': 25.0, 'q3': 48.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan},
 'Sports': {'q1': 22.0, 'med': 45.0, 'q3': 60.0, 'whislo': nan, 'whishi': nan}}


Seaborn's boxplot follows the standard box plot conventions:

whiskers at the lowest and highest datapoints, excluding outliers
a line at the median
a box between the 25% and 75% percentiles; these are the medians of the lower and of the higher half of the data

If you only provide 3 data points per box, these will be used for the whiskers and median line. The start and end positions of the box will be interpolated.
A trick would be to copy the data 3 times:

The median will stay at the "second rank" column of your dataframe
Due to the repeating, the 25% and 75% percentiles will be the "first" and "third rank".
The whiskers are ignored because they coincide with the box

(Note that your errorbar= parameter is ignored for boxplots, they have whiskers, no error bars. Also, native_scale=True is ignored because the y-axis isn't numeric.)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = [['Math', 3, 5, 15],
        ['English', 3, 10, 20],
        ['Computers', 5, 12, 30],
        ['Science', 8, 15, 32],
        ['Art', 17, 25, 48],
        ['Sports', 22, 45, 60]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Class', 'First Rank', 'Second Rank', 'Third Rank'])

df2 = pd.melt(df, ['Class'])
g = sns.catplot(x="value", y='Class', hue='Class', data=pd.concat([df2, df2, df2]), kind="box", orient="h", height=5,
                aspect=2)
g.set(xticks=(range(0, 80, 5)))
plt.show()


PS: Here are the percentiles calculated by numpy:
import numpy as np

values = [3, 5, 15]
for copies in [1, 2, 3]:
    data = values * copies
    print(f'copies: {copies}, data: {data}')
    for perc in [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]:
        print(f'  {perc}th percentile:', np.percentile(data, perc))

Output:
copies: 1, data: [3, 5, 15]
  0th percentile: 3.0
  25th percentile: 4.0
  50th percentile: 5.0
  75th percentile: 10.0
  100th percentile: 15.0
copies: 2, data: [3, 5, 15, 3, 5, 15]
  0th percentile: 3.0
  25th percentile: 3.5
  50th percentile: 5.0
  75th percentile: 12.5
  100th percentile: 15.0
copies: 3, data: [3, 5, 15, 3, 5, 15, 3, 5, 15]
  0th percentile: 3.0
  25th percentile: 3.0
  50th percentile: 5.0
  75th percentile: 15.0
  100th percentile: 15.0


Brilliant. Thank you so much for your help.
